# R Markdown Kable Cells Color with Condition

Tags: r, colors, r-markdown, tidyverse, kable

I am trying to create an R markdown file with PDF as an output not for HTML. I created a table where i need to color some cells (text) with red. Here is the code:

```
df %>%
  select(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7) %>%
  mutate(c7 = ifelse(cf %in% c("x", "y"), 
                            cell_spec(c7, "latex", 
                                      color = "red"), 
                            c7))%>%
  kable(caption = "df Name, booktabs = TRUE)
```

Now instead of getting the cell value in red, I just got this: \textcolor{red}{val}
I also tried text_color and the same output.

Can you please help me solve it. I tried the escape=F but it returns errors.

Comment: You need to tell kable not to escape the latex.

Comment: How should I do this? I stried ecape=F but nothing changed

Comment: `kable(caption = "df Name", booktabs = TRUE, escape = FALSE)` should work.

Comment: now it's working. the problem was the names of columns, they were something like c_1 and they were considered special characters.